# Unable sync my updated node stellar-core (v11.4.0), Please Help

Tags: stellar-core, history, catchup

## General information

We have a private network based on stellar.

I update the new release of stellar-core **v11.4.0** but, my node stuck on catching up state and restart over and over.

Our network nodes are on stellar-core version:

- 11.2.0 for test net
- 11.0.0 for live net

I try to sync for both of them but I have same problem.

## http-command info

we stack in this situation:

```
     "startedOn" : "2019-09-17T09:35:11Z",
      "state" : "Catching up",
      "status" : [
         "Catching up: Running: catchup : 1/2 children completed",
         "Armed with network upgrades: upgradetime=2000-01-01T00:00:00Z, protocolversion=11, basefee=1000, basereserve=1"
      ]
```

### Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Could you provide the config file (with secrets removed) and execution log? It's hard to tell from this question alone.

Answer (score 0):

## thank you for your reply

### this is my config file

```
PEER_PORT=****

RUN_STANDALONE=false
LOG_FILE_PATH=""
BUCKET_DIR_PATH="/data/buckets"

HTTP_PORT=*****
PUBLIC_HTTP_PORT=true
CATCHUP_COMPLETE=true
 
NODE_SEED="...."

NODE_IS_VALIDATOR=true

TARGET_PEER_CONNECTIONS=20

MAX_CONCURRENT_SUBPROCESSES=64

PREFERRED_PEERS=[
"stellar-core-2:8110", 
"stellar-core-3:8037"
]

PREFERRED_PEERS_ONLY=true

PREFERRED_PEER_KEYS=[
"$core-2", 
"$core-3"
]

FAILURE_SAFETY=0

UNSAFE_QUORUM=true

DATABASE="......"

NETWORK_PASSPHRASE="*******"

NODE_NAMES=[
"GASES2LBCKRQPGLU4MYQT7YYZZESE3GPGWOHOTBGZHUXAVLTH44WBM2J core-1",
"GCO7Q2UOKTXLHMWWROC7GUMW4PDJVHP4PYTLRIGCZW3FKW6TBA7FEVO6 core-2"
]

[QUORUM_SET]

THRESHOLD_PERCENT=51

[QUORUM_SET.0]
THRESHOLD_PERCENT=33

[QUORUM_SET.1]
THRESHOLD_PERCENT=33
VALIDATORS=[
"$core-2",
"$core-3"
]

[HISTORY.node1]
get="cp /var/kuknos/history/vs/{0} {1}"
put="cp {0} /var/kuknos/history/vs/{1}"
mkdir="mkdir -p /var/kuknos/history/vs/{0}"

[HISTORY.peer1]
get="curl -sfk https://history1-test.kuknos.org:8006/history/vs/{0} -o {1}"
```

### this my portion of log file

```
stellar-core-1_1  | 2019-09-18T06:59:20.777 GCMUL [Ledger WARNING] Out-of-order close during catchup, buffered to 1855364 but network closed 1855408
stellar-core-1_1  | 2019-09-18T06:59:20.777 GCMUL [Ledger WARNING] this round of catchup will fail and restart.
stellar-core-1_1  | 2019-09-18T06:59:20.777 GCMUL [History INFO] Catching up (discontiguous; will fail and restart): Running: catchup : 1/2 children completed
stellar-core-1_1  | 2019-09-18T06:59:20.806 GCMUL [Herder INFO] Quorum information for 1855407 : {"agree":3,"delayed":0,"disagree":0,"fail_at":3,"hash":"10529d","ledger":1855407,"missing":0,"phase":"EXTERNALIZE","validated":false}
stellar-core-1_1  | 
stellar-core-1_1  | 2019-09-18T06:59:20.806 GCMUL [Herder WARNING] Ledger 1855409 (32f2af) closed and could NOT be fully validated by validator
stellar-core-1_1  | 2019-09-18T06:59:20.827 GCMUL [Ledger INFO] Got consensus: [seq=1855409, prev=9d2044, txs=0, ops=0, sv: [ txH: 32f2af, ct: 1568789956, upgrades: [ ] ]]
```

### Is it necessary whole of my log file?